# How do I search for a special character using the character's code point in vim?

Tags: vim, hex, vi

I want to be able to find or replace a character in vi by using the decimal or hex number for a character. Like character 92 for example.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are we talking ASCII or Unicode or what?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To just search for the ASCII character with a hex value of 0x5c (which is 92 in decimal),
use the search pattern:

```
/\%x5c
```

If you want to search for all occurrences of that character in a file and replace them with another character (or characters), you can enter this command:

```
:%s/\%x5c/replacement text/gc
```

You can, of course, replace 5c with the ASCII hex value of whatever character you wish to replace.

I found this information [here](http://durgaprasad.wordpress.com/2007/09/25/find-replace-non-printable-characters-in-vim/) via a google search for "vim replace ascii character"